# Wait for Collection to be Updated

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I need a certain bit of code to wait for an item to be added to a collection.  The thread itself needs to wait until this completes before it continues.  The item gets added to the collection from another thread (kicked off from elsewhere), and I have no way to signal the current thread that this has occurred.

A naive implementation might look something like (ignoring thread safety on the collection, etc. for now):

```
public static List<string> myList = new List<string>();

public void WaitingMethod(string id)
{
    bool waiting = true;
    while (waiting)
    {
        int index = myList.IndexOf(id);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            waiting = false;
        }
    }

    //thread continues here
}
```

I believe this would block the thread and peg the processor.

What would be a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use ObservableCollection and listen to the CollectionChanged event then fire your method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you instead use an observable collection, and subscribe to CollectionChanged event?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly ObservableCollection<string> MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        private static AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        string item = i.ToString("0000");
                        MyList.Add(item);
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                });

            MyList.CollectionChanged += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            { if (eventArgs.NewItems.Cast<string>().Any(a => a.Equals("0005"))) resetEvent.Set(); };
            resetEvent.WaitOne();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is how you can also control the loop generating the items being added to the collection:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal class Program
    {
        #region Static Fields

        private static readonly CancellationTokenSource Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        private static readonly ObservableCollection<string> MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        private static readonly AutoResetEvent ResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !Cts.IsCancellationRequested; i++)
                    {
                        string item = i.ToString("0000");
                        MyList.Add(item);
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                },
                Cts.Token);
            Task finish = task.ContinueWith(antecedent => { Console.WriteLine("Task finished. Status {0}", antecedent.Status); });
            MyList.CollectionChanged += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                if (eventArgs.NewItems.Cast<string>().Any(a => a.Equals("0005")))
                {
                    Cts.Cancel();
                    ResetEvent.Set();
                }
            };
            ResetEvent.WaitOne();
            Task.WaitAll(finish);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I would still need to "pause" the thread somehow and have it wait until the right item was in the collection.  Otherwise the thread will complete.  I've been fiddling with async/await and an observable collection but can't figure out how to put it all together.

Answer (score 3):

As the others have said, use `ObservableCollection`.  But, you also need an `AutoResetEvent`:

1. In the class, during instantiation or program initialization, you register a Collection Changed event handler with the `ObservableCollection`.  When this method is called, it calls the `AutoResetEvent's Set` method to signal that the collection was changed.
2. When your thread gets to the point that it needs to wait, you wait for the `AutoResetEvent`.
3. Your other thread does its thing and changes the collection. That calls the method you registered with the collection, which raises the `AutoResetEvent`.  That signals your thread that's waiting to wake up.

This way, the thread that's waiting has no impact on the CPU.